# Verify if a matrix is reduced in ProLog

Tags: matrix, prolog

For the ones that I might have reached with my recent questions on my matrix operations project, I can actually confirm that everything is working perfectly...except one certain operation.
I'm talking of course on a function to check if a matrix is reduced to the Row Echelon Form, and as a newbie in functional/logic programming, it is really the most difficult task that I have yet faced.

So, to this function I need to check:

1. If the left-to-right diagonal has no zeros;
2. If the inferior matrix triangle is full of zeros.

This time I'm actually asking for total help as I don't even know how to start creating this mess, really hoping for a generous soul to execute this ambitious function and to please explain her way of thinking and procede.

Comment: FYI you are getting close votes. You should at a minimum make an attempt to show what data structure you are using and show an example of some valid and invalid matrices. Depending upon the need for a data structure one could consider a list of list or in certain cases with fixed matrix size use arg/3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having not heard of Row Echelon Form before, I found https://stattrek.com/matrix-algebra/echelon-form.aspx which tells me that there can be zeros in the left-to-right diagonal as long as each row "starts" later than the one before it. So I'm thinking:

- Count how many leading zeros there are in a row.

  - Manual recursion grind, if the start of the list is a zero then increment a counter, and recurse down the remaining elements. If the start is not a zero, stop counting.
- Building on that, the matrix is in Row Echelon Form if the number of leading zeros in this row is greater than in the previous row. I'm calling that a ratchet, as it can only increase.

  - Or if the row is all zeros.
  - and if this ratchet/all zeros holds for remaining rows.

```
% the number of leading zeros in a list [0,0,1,2,3] -> 2
row_leadZeroCount([],             LZC, LZC).
row_leadZeroCount([N|Ns], ZerosToHere, LZC) :-
    (N=0 -> (ZerosSeen is 1+ZerosToHere,
            row_leadZeroCount(Ns, ZerosSeen, LZC))
    ;       LZC = ZerosToHere).  % stop counting at the first non-zero.


% Nested lists are in Row Echelon Form if 
% the leading zeros in this row are more than the previous row
% or we're at a state of all remaining rows being only zeros.
matrix_ref_([], _, _).
matrix_ref_([Row|Rows], RowLen, Ratchet) :-
    row_leadZeroCount(Row, 0, RowZeros),
    (RowZeros < RowLen -> RowZeros > Ratchet
    ; RowZeros = RowLen),
    matrix_ref_(Rows, RowLen, RowZeros).


% wrapper to get row length, to see when a row is all zeros,
% and start the row length Ratchet going.
matrix_ref([Row|Rows]) :-
    length(Row, RowLen),
    matrix_ref_([Row|Rows], RowLen, -1).
```

e.g.

```
?- _Mx = [[1,2,3,4],    
          [0,0,1,3],
          [0,0,0,1],    %Example from linked web page
          [0,0,0,0]],
matrix_ref(_Mx).
true
```

NB. You say "reduced to the Row Echelon Form"; I'm ignoring the "Reduced Row Echelon Form" from that link, assuming that's not what you're asking for.